Salesforce and Mercado Pago
I'm looking for some examples or some information about integrations between Salesforce and Mercado Pago.
I need to integrate the paid market with Salesforce (when someone donates, it goes to SF as a contact and opportunity).
What I understand is that the payment market does not make much information available in the APIs about the people who donate to you, so I don't know if it is possible.
